# "Правочин", "договір" та "угода" тотожні чи ні?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, терміни, синоніми, legal-terms

Досить часто стикаючись з такими термінами як "правочин", "договір" та "угода", вирішив з'ясувати чи тотожні вони у своїх контекстах. Адже іноді важко зрозуміти, коли доцільно застосувати термін "правочин", коли — "договір", а коли — "угоду".

*Вікіпедія* пояснює, що:

> **[Правочи́н](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD)** — дія особи, спрямована на набуття, зміну або припинення цивільних прав і обов'язків.
>   «Правочин» є терміном, який раніше використовувався в українському законодавстві протягом 1920-1930-х років та застосований в новому Цивільному кодексі України, в якому йому відведено окрему главу. Раніше в цивільному праві вживався термін «угода», під яким розуміли вольові, правомірні дії громадян чи організацій, спрямовані на встановлення, зміну або припинення цивільних прав і обов'язків.
>   Ст. 202 Цивільного кодексу України визначає правочин як дію особи, спрямовану на набуття, зміну або припинення цивільних прав та обов'язків. Правочин, зокрема договір, є однією з найпоширеніших підстав виникнення, зміни та припинення цивільних правовідносин у системі юридичних фактів. [...]
>
> **[Договір](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2)** — домовленість двох або більше сторін, спрямована на встановлення, зміну або припинення цивільних прав та обов'язків. Договір може бути укладений у будь-якій формі, якщо вимоги щодо форми договору не встановлені законом (в тому числі в електронному вигляді).
>   Договори є правовими документами, де сторони визначаються із правами та обов'язками. [...]
>
> **[Угода](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)** — дії громадян і організацій, спрямовані на встановлення, зміну або припинення цивільних прав або обов'язків. Угоди можуть бути односторонніми і дво- чи багатосторонніми (договір).
>   Дії як юридичні факти завжди мають вольовий характер і поділяються на правомірні й неправомірні. Угоди — це вольові і правомірні дії, безпосередньо спрямовані на досягнення правового результату, а саме: на встановлення, зміну або припинення цивільних прав та обов'язків.
>   В угоді виявляється воля її учасників, яка має пізнаватися іншими особами, а тому повинна бути виражена, виявлена зовні. Зовнішній вияв волі називається волевиявленням. Це — суть угоди. Без волевиявлення немає угоди. Іноді для укладення угоди, крім волевиявлення, необхідно вчинити фактичні дії. [...]

І от, знайшовши на просторах Інетрнета статтю [Гордеюк А. О. "Проблема співвідношення категорій «правочин» та «договір» у цивільному законодавстві України"](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?I21DBN=LINK&P21DBN=UJRN&Z21ID=&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20&S21STN=1&S21FMT=ASP_meta&C21COM=S&2_S21P03=FILA=&2_S21STR=gumc_2014_4_13) від 2014 року, з'ясував, що фахівці таки їх розрізняють:

> [...] можна зробити висновки щодо співвідношення категорій «правочин» і «договір» у цивільному законодавстві України і в юридичній літературі. По-перше, об’єднує ці правові категорії їхня належність до юридичних фактів дії; по-друге, договір є різновидом правочину як юридичний факт дії, тому правочин зіставляється з договором як загальне й конкретне, при цьому кожний договір є правочином, але не кожний правочин є договором; по-третє, слід мати на увазі, що договір розуміють у цивільному (а відповідно й у договірному) праві в кількох аспектах (як юридичний факт дії, як зобов’язальні правовідносини і як документ), правочин же має ще більш складну правову природу, тому що передбачає як різновиди, крім правочину-договору, інші види правочинів [...]; по-четверте, поділ правочинів на односторонні та дво-, багатосторонні за критерієм наявності певної кількості сторін правочину, що беруть участь у здійсненні правочину, слід відрізняти від поділу договорів на односторонні та дво- й багатосторонні за іншим критерієм – наявності взаємних прав та обов’язків у сторін (контрагентів) договору.

Враховуючи наведений матеріал, **чим ці терміни ("правочин", "договір" та "угода") все-таки відрізняються**?

Comment: *Враховуючи наведений матеріал* (досить розлогий і детальний), які са́ме проблеми чи суперечності виникли у вас під час порівняння значень цих термінів?

Comment: Щодо "угоди" достатньо матеріалів не знайшов )

Comment: Наведені (розлогі) цитати наводять на думку, що *договір* — документ,  *угода* і *правочин* — дії, причому П. поступово приходить на заміну до У. Більш детальної відповіді надати неможливо унаслідок too broad характеру запитання. Якщо ваше запитання, натомість, про якийсь більш конкретний аспект, то варто вказати це у запитанні. І обрізати (розлогі) цитати десь на утричі.

Comment: Мені здається що звернення у відповідні державні органи щодо набуття чи виходу з громадянства не є довором, але це точно правочин.

Comment: Маю намір використовувати скрізь термін "угода" замість "договір". Наскільки це коректно?

Comment: Трішки скоротив, але треба скорочувати ще.

Answer (score 4):

Якщо говорити про сучасне юридичне розуміння цих термінів, то *"договір"* та *"угода"* є тотожними, а термін *"правочин"* ширшим за ці два.

---

Цивільний кодекс Української РСР 1963 року (який діяв до 2004 р.) не містив поняття "правочину", а послуговувався замість нього терміном "угода" (див. [Главу 3](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/1540-06#o191), "Угоди"). Останню було визначено так:

> **Стаття 41 ЦК УРСР. Поняття і види угод.**
>   Угодами визнаються дії громадян і організацій, спрямовані на встановлення, зміну або припинення цивільних прав або обов'язків.
>   Угоди можуть бути односторонніми і дво- або багатосторонніми (договори).

Чинний з 2004 р. Цивільний кодекс України ввів новий термін "правочин" (див. [Главу 16](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15#n1145) Розділу IV Книги першої ЦК України, "Правочини"). Цей термін перебрав на себе значення, яке раніше мала "угода":

> **Стаття 202 ЦК України. Поняття та види правочинів.**
>   1. Правочином є дія особи, спрямована на набуття, зміну або припинення цивільних прав та обов'язків.
>   2. Правочини можуть бути односторонніми та дво- чи багатосторонніми (договори).

Відповідно до цієї статті та статей 11, 626 ЦК України, ми маємо:

- *односторонні правочини*, які, за загальним правилом, можуть створювати обов'язки лише для особи, яка їх вчиняє (приклади: заповіт, довіреність)
- *дво- чи багатосторонні правочини*, які є погодженою дією двох або більше сторін (будь-які договори)

Отже, **договір** є одним із видів **правочинів**; це вужчий термін.

Що стосується **угоди**, то тепер це поняття тотожне договору - щоправда, термін "договір" більш усталений в законодавстві та юридичній практиці (наприклад, [Розділ ІІ](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15#n3110) Книги п'ятої ЦК України має назву "Загальні положення про договір".).

Ось як ці терміни пояснює [Верховний Суд України](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/n0003700-08#o16) (Узагальнення практики розгляду судами цивільних справ про визнання правочинів недійсними від 24.11.2008):

> Поява терміна "правочин" не виключає вживання терміна - "угода" у значенні домовленості між щонайменше двома сторонами. **Перший із них є більш широким і включає в себе терміни "договір", "угода", "домовленість".** Щоб запобігти неоднаковому застосуванню норм про правочини у практиці судів, слід зазначити, що **договір та угода є тотожними поняттями**, тому дво- і багатосторонні правочини є водночас як договорами, так і угодами, а термін "домовленість" слід розуміти як договір чи угоду, якщо така домовленість досягнута з дотриманням вимог, встановлених для укладення договору.

Більше на цю тему можна почитати в [Науково-практичному коментарі до ст. 202 ЦК України](http://legalexpert.in.ua/komkodeks/gk/79-gk/563-202.html) (автор коментаря до цієї статті - Дзера О. В.).

Comment: Вітаємо на сайті ukrainian.SE! Дуже дякуємо за розгорнуту відповідь із посиланнями на джерела. Складається враження, що ви самостійно розібрались із тим, як на цьому розділі stackexchange будується хороша відповідь. Наснаги вам і дякуємо, що долучилися!

Answer (score 0):

Необхідно сприйняти таку концепцію співвідношення зазначених термінів.

1. Двосторонні й багатосторонні правочини є договорами і водночас угодами.
2. Договори й угоди — тотожні поняття.
3. Термін «домовленість» необхідно розуміти як договір чи угоду, якщо такої домовленості досягнуто з дотриманням вимог, встановлених для укладання договору.

Таким чином, не кожний правочин є договором (угодою), а лише той, який опосередковує обопільну домовленість двох чи більше осіб, спрямовану на набуття, зміну або припинення цивільних прав та обов’язків.

Comment: Це фактично можна вважати коротким викладом написаного [тут](/a/5934), чи не так? (Чи зміст дещо відрізняється?)